# Power Pages -List UI breaks down on search and download

Tags: powerapps

I am new to power pages and recently I created a list in one of my webpages, but whenever I enable the search option or the download option the front page breaks and looks weird.
Attaching the screenshot for better understanding.

I tried re-creating the list as well, but no luck, I have not written any custom code on this particular webpage.
[image]